# How to get Sim Operator Name from Dual Sim Android Device.?

Tags: java, android

I have Dual Sim Android smartphone. I know there is no support for Dual Sim device in android SDK. I want to access a sim operator name of sim on default slot. But when I run program it gives me an empty string. Following is my code:

```
TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) 
getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String simOperatorName = telemamanger.getSimOperatorName();      
Toast.makeText(AmountActivity.this,simOperatorName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the full code to get sim names for any android devices.

```
//above 22
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
        //for dual sim mobile
        SubscriptionManager localSubscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(this);

        if (localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCount() > 1) {
         //if there are two sims in dual sim mobile
            List localList = localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
            SubscriptionInfo simInfo = (SubscriptionInfo) localList.get(0);
            SubscriptionInfo simInfo1 = (SubscriptionInfo) localList.get(1);

            final String sim1 = simInfo.getDisplayName().toString();
            final String sim2 = simInfo1.getDisplayName().toString();

        }else{
         //if there is 1 sim in dual sim mobile
            TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            String sim1 = tManager.getNetworkOperatorName();

        }

    }else{
        //below android version 22
                TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                String sim1 = tManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
telemamanger.getNetworkOperator()
```

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how and why it solves the problem and doesn’t introduce others.

Answer (score 0):

```
// To Get System TELEPHONY service ref
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
      .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

// Get Mobile No 
String pNumber= tManager.getLine1Number();

// Get carrier name (Network Operator Name)
String networkOperatorName= tManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```